# Books to learn WM6

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, mobile

Can someone suggest some literature about development under WM 6.0 via C# (sockets, bluetooth, user controls...).

Comment: As a 5 year veteran of Windows Mobile programming, can I give you some advice? Learn something else: iPhone, Android, Windows Phone 7, even BlackBerry. Windows Mobile is even more dead than Visual Basic, and brother that's dead! (I can make this comparison because I'm a *10* year veteran of VB).

Comment: Sank's, I know it ). But the customer want WM 6... So, what can I do?)

Comment: Try talking the customer into something else?

Comment: Oh, I'd like to ) But I'm only a junior developer. So... it's not an option )

Comment: WM6 is actually not a completely terrible idea from the customer's point of view. There are tons of devices available for sale for under $100, so you could equip a bunch of employees for next to nothing. I think that's really nickel-and-diming, though. A droid is $200 plus a service contract, which you'd probably have to provide to the employee anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This book covers the sockets and user controls. I don't recall any bluetooth mention.

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=10294&locale=en-us

My sincerest apologies for the punishment you are receiving by having to develop on this platform today. :)

Comment: +1 for the apologies - we all feel for this guy. :)

Comment: The only major realm where Windows Mobile is used at all these days is ruggedized handhelds (Intermec, Symbol etc.), and I have trouble believing that's going to continue for long.

Comment: @MusiGenesis - It seems like Android is a much better platform for the ruggedized handheld development market. Unfortunately, there is a lot of investment in drivers to attached hardware. I think you are right in that WM's days are numbered in this space.

Comment: Ok. As for bluetooth. How can i test it without physical device (emulator only)? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @Pritorian: abandon the emulator fantasy *right now!* :) It's so close to completely useless that you can go ahead and assume it's completely useless.  Just buy a device on eBay.

Comment: @Dennis: ironically, I think Windows CE (the underpinning of WM6) is *by far* the most mature and stable device OS out there. This makes sense given that it was the result of a culling-down of an already-proven OS, as compared to the obviously haphazard growth (in a literal sense) of Android, the programmatical anarchy of the iPhone world, and the utter disaster that is BlackBerry.